# Leaflet Draw - Editing Polygon: changing Polygon points does not reset Polygon edit points

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

i am currently working on a functionality, where a user can create and edit zones (polygons). Therefore I am using a class Zone which extends L.Polygon. To edit a specific instance of Zone I am using `specificZone.editing.enable()`. This is working and looks like this:
[image: Editing zone]

Now I can move the points around to edit the zone like this:
[image: Moving edit points]

If I then cancel the editing with the following code:

```
specificZone.setLatLngs(oldZoneLatLngs); //oldZoneLatLngs were saved when editing was enabled
specificZone.editing.disable();
```

the zone again looks like this:

[image: old zone]

But if I now want to edit the zone again the old zone edit point are displayed again:

[image: old zone with wrong edit points]

Has anyone experienced something like this?

I am thankful for any kind of help :)

Kind regards
Luca